# How to find all the available filter for CPPLINT.cfg file?

Tags: c++, cpplint

I'm using [EditConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) to enforce 2 spaces indentation.

```sh
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
continuation_indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
```

I start using cpplint for static analysis, everything worked well until I found that some rules makes conflicts with my EditorConfig configurarion, I'm trying to disable this cpplint rules"

```sh
private: should be indented +1 space inside class
public: should be indented +1 space inside class
```

The help says I can use filters to disable specific check, but I can find a list of all filters available.

```sh
Example file:
        filter=-build/include_order,+build/include_alpha
```

Do you know the names of the filters I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was so easy, I just need to look carefully on the error message, it shows the name at the end of the message between "[]"

```sh
LinuxFilesManager.hpp:7:  private: should be indented +1 space inside class LinuxFilesManager  [whitespace/indent] [3]
```

The solution was creating the CPPLINT.cfg file like this:

```sh
set noparent

filter=-whitespace/indent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all available filter for the `--filter` option in the source code [cpplint.py](https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint/blob/develop/cpplint.py). They're part of the variable `_ERROR_CATEGORIES`. There is no way to print them using `cpplint` command.

Please refer to the `cpplint.py` file you've installed as you may have installed either the Google original version or the forked version.